# json file_get_contents and show item

Tags: php, json

I have this code but I can't make the items to show properly, I can only show the data from echo $data sentence but not $item FirstName or Item Bio

```
$url = 'https://jdublu.com/api/wrsc/json_employee.php?RID=17965'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$items = json_decode($data, true); 

foreach ($items as $item)
{
$name = $item = ["FirstName"];
$bio = $item = ["Bio"];
}

echo $data
```

Comment: Please, read php basics. `$name = $item = ["FirstName"];` does not what you expect.

Comment: $name = $item["FirstName"];
    $bio = $item["Bio"];

Answer (score 0):

if you see the json response it has 2 elements. 
`{`
`message : ...`,
`department : ....`
`}`

so you have to loop throw `$items['department']` rather than `$items`
and you can access the data like `$item['Bio']`

So you can change the code like this to get the information

```
<?php 
   $url = 'https://jdublu.com/api/wrsc/json_employee.php?RID=17965'; 
   $data = file_get_contents($url); // into a variable
   $items = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed
   foreach ($items['department'] as $item)
   {
       $name = $item["FirstName"];
       $bio = $item["Bio"];
       echo $name . ' ' . $bio . PHP_EOL;
   }
```